# Combining columns in Multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, correlation, multi-index, finance

Good morning everyone. I have a multi-index dataframe with stocks’ variables. In particular I need to have correlation coefficients in a combined column for each ticker rather than in a separated corr matrix. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Hi @Adelchi La Rosa, welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to check how to ask a question. In general, include code such that we can reproduce your issue. Including what you have tried so far would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
ticker = si.tickers_sp500()

start = dt.datetime.today()-dt.timedelta(2500)
end = dt.datetime.today()
stock = yf.download(ticker,start, end ,interval='1d')
stock = stock.dropna(how='all')

for t in ticker:
  stock['returns', t] =  stock['Adj Close',t].pct_change()

---> mean-variance optimization portfolio?!?!?!?!?

  stock['Buy Signal',t] = np.where(................)
```

---

Now after downloading this huge dataframe, I want to backtest a trading strategy based on technical analysis. Before to launch the buy signal I want to include the mean-variance optimization for portfolio. But the problem is that, in order to mantain the multi-index data structure, I don't know how to figure out. I know that it makes poor sense having a column with double tickers since I would lose the for loop based on t.

Thanks again